# Call method with covariant generic type specified in supplied parameter

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

The `out` keyword below is (as I didn't know, but for reasons that may be obvious to you) not allowed:

```
public static class DataExtensions {
    public static void ReplaceAll<T>(this EntityCollection<T> collectionToReplace, IEnumerable<T> collectionToAdd) where T : EntityObject {
        RemoveEach(collectionToReplace);
        foreach (T item in collectionToAdd) collectionToReplace.Add(item);
    }

    public static void RemoveEach(this EntityCollection<out EntityObject> collectionToEmpty) {
        if (!collectionToEmpty.IsLoaded) collectionToEmpty.Load();
        while (collectionToEmpty.Any()) collectionToEmpty.Remove(collectionToEmpty.First());
    }
}
```

and without it `RemoveEach(collectionToReplace);` has a parameter mismatch:

`Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<T>' to 'System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject>'`

The same, when calling with a specific (non-generic) derived type. Do I have to do use the following signature?

```
public static void RemoveEach<T>(this EntityCollection<T> collectionToEmpty) where T : EntityObject {
```

If so, intellisense or the compiler should warn me about using an abstract class as the generic type-specifier in this method, because I've just created an un-callable method, no? And if you don't mind, would you please point out why this is so (e.g. a scenario where type-safety would be broken or confusion would result if it were allowed).

Thank you, Shannon

Comment: p.s. I realize this usage of EF will have performance issues on large data volumes.

Comment: RemoveEach() is used rather than .Clear() with the intention of supporting operations like .ReplaceAll() above it, without calls to .SaveChanges() or multiple concurrent contexts.

Comment: also, although I clearly have an answer by a knowledgeable poster below, I'd still love to hear why the C# spec doesn't allow this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to use:

```
public static void RemoveEach<T>(this EntityCollection<T> collectionToEmpty)
    where T : class
{
    if (!collectionToEmpty.IsLoaded) collectionToEmpty.Load();
    while (collectionToEmpty.Any()) collectionToEmpty.Remove(collectionToEmpty.First());
}
```

That's the only constraint that `EntityCollection<T>` requires, and you're not using anything within the method body which needs `EntityObject`.

By the way, is what you're doing here very different to calling `collectionToEmpty.Clear()`? I haven't used EF for a while, so it's not entirely obvious...

Comment: Yay, my first personal drive-by Skeeting! ;) Ok, thanks for the info, I also take your answer to mean generics ARE required. Regarding "is [it] different", .Clear() would require multiple calls to context.SaveChanges(), effectively preventing me from implementing this sugar without supporting multiple concurrently contexts. As I understand it, the method shown here will behave properly this way, but I'll report back...